# Polynomial with $k$ positive and $k+1$ negative zeroes

Tags: polynomials

> A polynomial of degree $n$ is written in standard form. All numerical
>    coefficients are positive. It has $k$ positive zeroes and $k+1$
>    negative zeroes. $0$ is not a zero of the polynomial. What can we deduce
>    about $n$?

The answer in the book said

> $n=1$

I, however, got the answer

> $n=1,5,9,13,17,21,\dots$

How do you eliminate the leftover cases ($5,9,13,\dots)$?

EDIT: Note, as per the comments, that $n$ is meant to be $2k+1$.

Comment: Presumably you've considered the last coefficient to eliminate the cases $3,7,11...$. Perhaps consider another coefficient?

Comment: Let the polynomial be $P(x)$.

If all numerical coefficients are positive, what can we say about $P(x)$ when $x>0$?

Comment: Is $k$ supposed to have any relation to $n$?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Yes, $n=2k+1$ as we have $n$ roots, of which $k$ are positive and $k+1$ negative.

Comment: Then please edit that information into the question. The way the question is currently written, the polynomial $(x+1)(x^2+1)$ satisfies the conditions with $n=3$ and $k=0$.

Comment: Never mind, I did it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a polynomial $f(X)$ has positive coefficients, and $0$ is not a root, it has only negative roots. Hence $k=0$. Thus is decomposition into a product of irreducible factors over $\mathbf R$ has the form:
$$f(X)=c(X+a)p_1(X)\dotsm p_r(X),$$
where the $p_i(X)$ are quadratic polynomials with a negative discriminant. Thus the degree $n$ is odd.

Comment: What about $(x-100)^2(x+1)^3$? It has 3 negative and 2 positive roots. $k=2$ and $n=5$

Comment: I supposed the O.P. meant *distinct* roots. And this one  has a negative coefficient.

Comment: What about $(x+100)^3(x-1)^2$

Comment: As I said, I supposed the hypotheses were about distinct roots..

Comment: It could also be written as $(x+99.9)(x+100)(x+100.1)(x-0.99)(x-1.01)$. This now has $5$ distinct roots.

Comment: It also has a negative coefficient. If a polynomial has positive coefficients, it can't have a positive root.

Comment: Ok, I got it. If all coefficients are positive, and you multiply these with powers of positive numbers (roots), you still get a positive answer (and not zero). Thanks!